# Regra ESLint para forçar usar apenas "it" ou "test" nos testes

Tags: javascript, jest, eslint

Aqui no projeto temos essa despadronização, em alguns arquivos é utilizado o `it` e em outros é utilizado o `test`.

Existe alguma forma de controlar isso com uma regra do ESLint ou algum outro método?

Answer (score 3):

Existe o plugin [eslint-plugin-jest](https://github.com/jest-community/eslint-plugin-jest) que contém diversas regras de ESLint para o Jest, uma delas é a [consistent-test-it](https://github.com/jest-community/eslint-plugin-jest/blob/main/docs/rules/consistent-test-it.md). Ao adicionar essa biblioteca como dependência do projeto e adicionar `'jest'` dentro de `plugins` no seu `.eslintrc`, já estará apto a usar as regras do plugin.

O modo de uso básico da regra é:

```
// Aceita apenas `test`
'jest/consistent-test-it': ["error", {"fn": "test"}]
```

Caso deseje um comportamento diferente dentro e fora de um `describe`, pode usar:

```
// Aceita apenas `it` fora do `describe` e `test` dentro do `describe`
'jest/consistent-test-it': ["error", {"fn": "it", "withinDescribe": "test"}]
```

A configuração padrão é para `test` fora do `describe` e `it` dentro.